# Unexpected error from import statsmodels.api as sm

Tags: python, python-import, statsmodels

I've been using statsmodels for a long time now - always importing it using

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

But today, seemingly out of the blue, this error is raised:

> AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'api'

Of course `sm.version.version` raises an error too, but

```
import statsmodels
statsmodels.__version__
```

returns  `'0.6.1'`

I've tried reinstalling following the [docs](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/install.html)

But entering the command `pip install -U statsmodels` only returns:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

I'm Windows 7 running Python 3.6.0

`sys.version:`

```
3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Anaconda, so why am I messing around with pip in this case? The truth is that I really don't know.

This sorted out the issue:

```
conda install statsmodels
```

By the way, I think the reason why I messed things up was because I tried to install an arima package a few days ago.